# Puzzled about the ASP.NET MVC DefaultControllerFactory.cs Implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

While investigating implementing my own `IControllerFactory` I looked into the the default implementation `DefaultControllerFactory` and was surprised to see the `RequestContext` property being set in the `CreateController(...)` method, and then being referenced in the `GetControllerInstance(...)` and `GetControllerType(...)` methods.

The reason for my surprise is that as the factory is instantiated at Application start-up that same instance is used for all requests, so if multiple requests are received at the same time you have no guarantee which requests `RequestContext` has been set to the property when you come to use it.

Is there a guarantee in the MVC framework that only one request will be serviced by the registered `IControllerFactory` at a time?

If I am missing something here please enlighten me, as the implementaiton of my controller will be simpler if I have state between method calls during a requests lifecycle.

Thanks.

EDIT:

The answers given are as I expected but miss the main point of the question. The fact is the DefautlControllerFactory supplied as a part of the MVC framework is storing the RequestContext as if it has state - look at the source.

I believe this to be wrong and am looking for clarification (which I think I have seeing as both answers agree with my thoughts). I have cross posted to thte ASP.NET MVC Forums.

Comment: I don't get your point. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross posting to the ASP.NET MVC forums reveals this to be a bug with the DefaultControllerFactory implementation.

See here for information:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1414677.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1404189.aspx

The latter post however reveals that you can have a controller factory be instatiated on each request, in which case you can have state.

From the post...

> ```
> ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(typeof(DefaultControllerFactory));
> ```
>
> This will switch the mode of the
>   controller builder from instance-based
>   to type-based, and will create a new
>   instance of the controller factory on
>   every request.

Answer (score 0):

Your question: Is there a guarantee in the MVC framework that only one request will be serviced by the registered IControllerFactory at a time?

Answer: No, you have to use locks to store state.

My question: Why do you want to store state in the controller factory?

Answer (score 0):

No the Controller factory CreateController method is executed for each request. In application startup you are only suppose to set your default controller and creating a new controller factory is only three lines of code:

```
public class CommonServiceLocatorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory  
{  
  protected override IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)  
  {  
    return (controllerType == null) ? base.GetControllerInstance(controllerType) 
     : ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;  
  }
}
```